# $Z^n = (Z + 1)^n$ roots in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the roots of the equation $Z^n = (Z + 1)^n$ and show that the points which represent them are collinear on the complex plane.

Comment: $(\frac{z}{z+1})^n=1$

Comment: $Z$ can't be $0$. Solve first $X^n=1$. and then $(Z+1)/Z=X$.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

- $\dfrac{Z}{Z+1} = \omega_k\,$ where $\,\omega_k \mid k = 1,\ldots n-1\,$ are the non-unit $\,n^{th}\,$ roots of unity;
- the $\omega_k$ all lie on the unit circle, and $Z = \dfrac{\omega}{1-\omega}$
  is a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) which maps circles and lines to circles and lines.

Answer (score 2):

For the collinear part:

$z^n = (z + 1)^n \implies |z|=|z+1| \implies x^2+y^2=(x+1)^2+y^2 \implies x= \dfrac 12$.